# jQuery FancyBox YouTube videos not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a situation whereby I cannot modify the HTML code for the anchor tag, with the exception of the 'href' attribute. So adding a class to the anchor tag is not an option.

The HTML markup is as follows:

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=#########&amp;autoplay=1"></a>
```

To distinguish between this and other links, I have added a selector based on the 'href' to the jQuery code.

The code is as follows:

```
(function ($) { 

  $('a[href*="youtube"]').fancybox({
            'padding' : 0,
            'type' : 'swf',
            'href' : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
            'swf' : { 'wmode' : 'transparent', 'allowfullscreen' : 'true' }
            });
e.preventDefault();

})(jQuery);
```

This does not seem to be working at all. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong? I am using Drupal, hence why I have added the part at the top to enable to '$'.

I cannot see any errors in the console, the page simply navigates straight to the YouTube page with no JavaScript intervention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
adding a class to the anchor tag is not an option
```

That is not necessarily true since you can always add the class via jQuery like

```
$('a[href*="youtube"]').addClass("fancybox")
```

Anyway, personally I don't like to use the `swf` mode for youtube videos any more but `iframe` mode; that makes them easier to handle and cross-platform compatible (including iOS)

What I would do is, using the `.each()` method :

- convert every single `href` to `embed` format using javascript `.replace()`
- bind each anchor to fancybox
- set the new converted `href` using the fancybox `href` API option

This is the code that works for both fancybox v1.3.4 or v2.x :

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href*=youtube]').each(function () {
        // convert youtube swf href to embed for iframe
        var thisHref =  this.href
                       .replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'embed/')
                       .replace(new RegExp("&", "i"), '?');
        // bind fancybox to each anchor
        $(this).fancybox({
            "padding" : 0,
            "type" : "iframe",
            // add trailing parameters to href (wmode)
            "href" : thisHref + "&amp;wmode=opaque"
        }); // fancybox
    }); // each
  }); // ready
})(jQuery);
```

**Notice** that I added `wmode=opaque`, otherwise the close button will be behind the youtube video.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZHdaR/)** with version 1.3.4 ... or **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yZWv3/)** with v2.1.4

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the `doc ready` handler inside the closure and there is no need for the `e.preventDefault()`:

```
(function ($) { 
   $(function(){
     $('a[href*="youtube"]').fancybox({
        'padding' : 0,
        'type' : 'swf',
        'href' : this.href.replace(/watch?v=/gi, 'v/'),
        'swf' : { 'wmode' : 'transparent', 'allowfullscreen' : 'true' }
     });    
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. However I now get the following error in the console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined .